# What is the lowest component cost way to detect ~50 mA current flow?

Tags: current, current-measurement

I'm looking for a method to detect when a power output connector is in use and I imagine the best way(?) to do this would be to monitor the current, which is guaranteed to be >50 mA @ 5 V. Essentially my system must know when something is connected to its 5 V supply output.

I don't need to know the exact current, just whether it is flowing or not. Ideally I'd want to monitor on the high-side.

The signal will feed into a microcontroller, but there isn’t any decent ADC available which could measure in the ~50 mV range, which is probably the maximum burden voltage I could afford using a shunt resistor.

I have to keep component cost low, however, so simple and cheaper solutions are favourable.

I'd be keen to hear how others might approach this. My current thought is a comparator, but maybe there are other ways.

Comment: You might want to tell us more about your application. This might be an XY-problem.

Comment: _"...measure in the ~50mV range, which is probably the max burden voltage I could afford using a shunt resistor."_ - What is the maximum expected current draw?

Comment: There are some cheap current sense amps like NCS199

Comment: Yes, more detail - definitely sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: speculating on a bit more of what might be there (comparator-shunt folks have the most standard ways covered): if this is the only user of the 5V, it is likely possible to integrate with circuit producing or regulating the 5V to detect (that circuit itself has to react to current draw after all!) likely at least saving some resistors.  if there are other things drawing on the 5V, it doesn't work due to false positives from the other device.

Comment: Which MCU, and what is its supply voltage?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you're monitoring the current on the low side, you can use a comparator or op-amp with a relatively low offset voltage.

For example, half of an LM393 comparator has an offset voltage of maximum +/-3mV so if you set it up with a (say) 12mV reference divider and a shunt of perhaps 0.5\$\Omega\$ you can detect a 50mA current to ground.

The comparator is 5 or 10 cents in moderate quantity and the 4 required resistors are next to nothing.

To detect a current with a shunt on the high side would require a more modern R-R input comparator or op-amp.

[image]

If you need to do any filtering, firmware would be preferred in the modern era.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

[image: Comparator-based highside shunt detector]

Idea:

When no current flows, both sides of R3 have the same potential, so that the inverting input of the comparator is at VCC/2. The non-inverting input is at a little more – because R5 is larger than R4.

When 50 mA flow, then there's 50 mV drop over R3.

Tune R3 and R5 such that you get in inverting input higher than the non-inverting one when you hit the current at which you want to start asserting the "detect" output.

In this case, I chose R5 to be 20% larger than R4, which is not acceptable for this application. You want VCC·R5/(R4+R5) = (VCC-25mV)/2, or similar.

You'll need to use relatively high-precision resistors (0.1 %); these aren't really "expensive" expensive, but that's not your standard resistor.

Of course, the comparator is the "expensive" part here. But a simple comparator from discrete semiconductors isn't hard to build, should you really need to squeeze component pennies.

Comment: And hysteresis handled in software? Or by selection of the op amp?

Comment: hysteresis is not part of the system spec, far as I can tell, @PeterMortensen. But you're of course right, at least adding a capacitor for increased noise immunity is wise.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use 5 V - just connect it to a digital pin of the microcontroller.

If ground or safety doesn’t allow to do that, use a [photocoupler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opto-isolator); it costs about 2 cents.

If you are not allowed to use 'voltage', that is, a far connection, and are only allowed to use local measurements, then a [Hall sensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect_sensor) can detect the current directly in the wire. But it is a bit more costly—10 cents or so.

Comment: He wants to measure current with a 50 mV drop max

Answer (score 0):

Two component solution:

1. Current sense amplifier like INA240
2. Shunt resistor

INA240 can be used to measure both high (up to 80V common mode range) and low sides.

Comment: Great idea - except that chip is out of stock at every supplier I checked!

Comment: Maybe other ones will be okay? https://www.ti.com/amplifier-circuit/current-sense/overview.html or https://www.analog.com/en/product-category/current-sense-amplifiers.html If TI & ADI are totally out of stock you could perhaps search for "current sense amplifier ic".